# 1 Jn. 2:6 reports that someone walked, is this someone God? The Father, Jesus or both in one person?

Tags: referent-identification, 1-john

> "He that saith he abideth in him ought himself also so to walk, even as he walked." (1 Jn. 2:6 KJV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, the Greek word translated here as "walk" is "περιπατέω" and is defined by Strong as:

> περιπατέω peripatéō, per-ee-pat-eh'-o; from G4012 and G3961; to tread
> all around, i.e. walk at large (especially as proof of ability);
> figuratively, to live, deport oneself, follow (as a companion or
> votary):—go, be occupied with, walk (about).

In other words, while it can refer to literal walking, it is also used in a figurative sense to refer to one's deportment.

Jesus made it clear that he lived in obedience to the Father and that the Father was in him.

> And he that sent me is with me: the Father hath not left me alone; for
> I do always those things that please him. (John 8:29, KJV)
>
> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the
> words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that
> dwelleth in me, he doeth the works. (John 14:10, KJV)

Because the Father is God--the only true God, according to Jesus (see John 17:1-3), and because the Father was in Jesus, one might say that in a sense God Himself walked among us while Jesus was on the earth.  That is, in fact, the meaning of "Emmanuel": "God with us."  As a man, Jesus was one of us.  No human can ever be God.  But God's Spirit dwelt in Christ.

> To wit, that **God was in Christ,** reconciling the world unto himself,
> not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us
> the word of reconciliation. (2 Corinthians 5:19, KJV)

**Conclusion**

We are to walk, even as Christ walked while on this earth--meaning we are to live in obedience to the Father just as Jesus did.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest we need to look at the wider context of the verse and go back to the beginning of the chapter.

"We have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous" (v1, RSV).

The following verses then expand on the reference to Jesus Christ. "He" is the expiation for our sins, in v2. We may be sure that we know "him" if we keep his commandments (vv3-4). We need to keep "his" word in v5. That is how we may be sure that we are "in him" (being "in Christ" is also a Pauline usage) in v5. V6 is then comtinuing the topic of abiding "in him", i.e. in Christ, which indicates that "walking in the same way in which he walked" is also continuing the original train of thought about Jesus Christ the righteous.

Comment: Your post reminded me of 1 John 5:20.